# Neither light exposes him Nor darkness hides him

Tags: single-word-requests, word-usage, expressions

"Neither light exposes him Nor darkness hides him"

It's used in an Arabic story, and I want to translate the whole story into English , so I wonder If it is right beacause it is a literal translation ! Is its meaning clear to English readers ?
Is there any grammatical error in my translation ?

Comment: With the exception that `Nor` should not be capitalised, it looks fine to me.

Comment: It sounds like old-fashioned grammar to me (although the meaning is completely clear, and translating an Arabic story with old-fashioned grammar might be appropriate). A more modern rendition would be *Neither does light expose him nor does darkness hide him.*

Comment: Yes, this is old-fashioned phrasing.  But if this is an old-fashioned Arabic story, or an Arabic story written about times long ago, your phrase would be good.  Of course, then you would do the rest of the translation with archaic-sounding phrasing.  That could be effective.  But it could be difficult to do, unless you often read such things in English.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's understandable, but it comes over as a very literary form (which might be what you want), for two reasons.

First, "Neither .. nor" can coordinate many different grammatical constructs: noun phrases (*I drink neither tea nor coffee.*), verb phrases (*I neither want nor expect your thanks*) and complete predicates (*I neither watched TV nor went to the park*), but it doesn't usually coordinate whole sentences, as in your example. It can do, but it's uncommon in ordinary speech, and feels literary.

Secondly, when "neither" does stand first in a clause in this way, it tends to behave like other negative-polarity terms, and trigger inversion:

> *Scarcely had he left the room ...* (not *Scarcely he had left the room ...*)
>
> *Never could I imagine that!* (not *Never I could imagine that!*)

So your example would more commonly be

> Neither does light expose him, nor does darkness hide him.

This is a tendency, so what you have said is not ungrammatical in the way that *Never I could imagine that!* would be; but to me it makes it very literary, almost archaic. It does sound better in a poetic sense, though.

Comment: I like that. I wonder whether Arabic has the equivalent of the "does <noun> 
<verb>" grammatical structure, I suspect that it might be pretty much unique to English because of the nature of English infinitives. If Arabic doesn't have that form then your suggestion is a literal translation just as much as the one the OP gives.

Comment: Modern English's requirement for "do-support" in negatives and interrogatives is unusual, but similar structures are found in other languages. (It's nothing to do with the English infinitive: it's because English has abandoned the traditional "_verb_ not" except for auxiliaries). I doubt that Arabic has anything that works that way, but there may be other constructions which involve more than one verb: I'm pretty sure there are in Biblical Hebrew.